# Android Use ImageView Button to open navigation drawer

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make an image view click open navigation drawer. This is the code i have in main activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start"
    tools:context="zw.zse.direct.activities.client.HomeActivity">

<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_nav_drawer"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

        <include layout="@layout/top_header"
            android:id="@+id/top_header"/>

        <WebView
            android:layout_below="@+id/top_header"
            android:id="@+id/webview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_below="@+id/webview"
            android:id="@+id/fragment_placeHolder"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_navigation">
        </FrameLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomNavigationView.Colored"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu" />

    </RelativeLayout>


    <!--bottom sheet container -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>

This is the code for the top_header.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<!--Top Header Layout-->
<LinearLayout
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:id="@+id/topbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_arrow_back_24" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp">

        <ImageView
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:id="@+id/history"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:padding="6dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_history" />


    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I want to make it that when the imageview(id = back) is clicked, navigation drawer opens, nd can be toggled.

This is the current java code i have. The theme i am using has no action bar.

```
DrawerLayout drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    menuIcon = findViewById(R.id.back);
    menuIcon.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_menu));
    menuIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //open navigation drawer
            drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);

        }
    });
```

At the moment with this code the activity starts with the drawer open and i cannot close it